# DirectX SDK (June 2010) Installation: Error Code S1023

Tags: directx, uninstallation

So I got error S1023 for my installation. I don't want to install the SDK anymore on this computer but the installer left programs that now i can't uninstall. EX:DirectX Control Panel. Tried running the uninstaller located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\system\uninstall but it says i need to launch it from the control panel. Directx SDK doesn't even show up on the control panel!! What do i do ?

Answer (score 0):

The legacy DirectX SDK has a few known issues including the one that gives rise to S1023. See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/known-issue-directx-sdk-june-2010-setup-and-the-s1023-error/).

You can just delete the folder and then remove any short-cuts that no longer work.

Note that the latest versions of DirectX Control Panel are included in the Windows SDK.

Comment: So i can delete the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010) and ill be fine ?

Comment: Yes. The "DirectX End-User Runtime" aka. the D3DX, etc. stuff is in System32 and isn't uninstalled by the SDK anyhow.